# Reference indicator from within a Pine script

Tags: pine-script

Let's say I want to include the AO indicator as part of the criteria for my Pine script. How can a pine script access indicators? Can a strategy or study import a series generated by another Pine script or built-in indicators?

Answer (score 5):

You can't access indicators if they're not provided by built-in functions.
In your specific case of the Awesome Oscillator, you could calculate it yourself to get the series values.
See [Awesome Oscillator (AO)](https://www.tradingview.com/support/solutions/43000501826-awesome-oscillator-ao/) for how it's calculated.

edit:
I just found out that it does seem to be possible if the desired indicator is on your chart.
See [How can I use one script’s output as an input into another?](https://www.pinecoders.com/faq_and_code/#how-can-i-use-one-scripts-output-as-an-input-into-another)

Screenshot of example with the Awesome Oscillator:

[image: External Indicator]

Comment: And if you were to use this `AO:AO` as a source, every time you make modifications to the code where Pine thinks it affected input arguments, it will reset it to `Close`.
Also there is a Copy function on the right-click menu of your Indicators/Strategies. Now if you use another indicator as a source for your indicator, then this Copy function disappears.

Answer (score 0):

While indicators does not offer reusability in the way you mentioned. But, new libraries will surely does.

Have a look at libraries and examples of some indicators using them.

https://www.tradingview.com/scripts/?script_type=libraries

Not sure if awesome oscillator is present as part of any library. Feel free to write one if you think it can be useful.